# Многоточие, когда много пунктов в меню

Tags: php, pagination

Сейчас генерирую ссылки на страницы меню таким кодом:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_of_pages; $i++) {

  $actual = $i + 1;
  if($i === intval($page)){
    echo "<a  id=\"now\" href=\"http://site.com/index.php?page=".$i."\">".$actual."</a>&nbsp;"; 
  } else {
    echo "<a id=\"other\" href=\"http://site.com/index.php?page=".$i."\">".$actual."</a>&nbsp;";
  }

}
```

И он выводит все количество страниц в меню. Как можно сделать ограничение, так, чтобы с каждой стороны от актуальной страницы выводилось по 2 предыдущих/следующих, а вместо оставшихся многоточие.
Допустим:

`1` 2 3 ...

1 `2` 3 4 ...

1 2 `3` 4 5 ...

... 2 3 `4` 5 6 ...

Пока идей, как это отслеживать грамотно, не пришло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id=other` - это нехорошо. id предполагает уникальное значение.

> https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters.

Вместо ID лучше использовать Class

А теперь по делу:

```
// Получили $page, проверили на границы (больше 0, меньше $num_of_pages)
$page= min($num_of_pages-1, max(0, intval($_GET['page'])));

// Теперь рассчитаем, границы, какие будем показывать
$from = max(0, $page-2); // меньше на 2 страницы, но не меньше 0
$to = min($num_of_pages-1, $page+2); // больше на 2 страницы, но не больше $num_of_pages

// если начинаем не с 0, то показать многоточие
if ($from!==0){
  echo "&hellip;";
}

for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++) {
  echo ' <a class='.($i===$page ? "now" : "other").' href="http://site.com/index.php?page='.$i.'">'.($i+1).'</a> ';
}

// если закончили не последней страницей, показать многоточие
if ($to!==$num_of_pages-1){
  echo "&hellip;";
}
```